# c# Activator.CreateInstace how do i cast to generic base type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting

I'm attempting to build a deck of cards (there are many different types of decks of cards) using generics based on derived types for suit, color, rank. I'm having an issue in how to create them using reflection and then cast the resulting object to the base PlayingCard type PlayingCard

```
    public class Name {}
    public class SpadesName : Name {}

    public class Color {}
    public class BlackColor : Color {}

    public class Rank {}
    public class AceRank : Rank {}

    public class PlayingCard<TName, TColor, TRank>
     where TName: Name, new()
     where TColor: Color, new()
     where TRank: Rank, new()
    {}

    public class DeckOfCards
    {
    public PlayingCard<Name, Color, Rank>[] cards;

    public DeckOfCards() {}

    public void BuildDeckOfCards()
    {
        this.cards = new PlayingCard<Name, Color, Rank>[52];

        Type[] fpcTypeArgs = { typeof(SpadesName), typeof(BlackColor), typeof(AceRank) };
        Type fpcType = typeof(PlayingCard<,,>);
        Type constructable = fpcType.MakeGenericType(fpcTypeArgs);

        // the problem is here.. this will not cast.
        // how do I create an object using reflection and cast it to the generic base type PlayingCard<Name, Color, Rank>
        var fpc = Activator.CreateInstance(constructable);
        this.cards[0] = fpc; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: That is about the worst generics abuse I've seen in years. Why would you ever use generics in that way? Simply create a `Card` class with `Suit` and `Rank` properties.

Comment: @InBetween yes, I knew these types of comments would be posted, in record time no less.. as the post states, i'm trying to solve this using generics. There is a larger picture here you don't see. I am well aware that this can be done concretely. Please respect the reason for the post.

Comment: No amount of run-time reflection is going to change the fact that `PlayingCard<Name, Color, Rank>` and `PlayingCard<SpadesName, BlackColor, AceRank>`  are distinct types. If you create an instance of the latter, you cannot store it in an array of the former. What you're really after may or may not be possible, but if you don't want to show what that is and don't want others to address that in an answer, I don't see any way of giving a useful answer to this question.

Comment: *There is a larger picture here you don't see*. Well then, begin by saying so in the first place, more so if you are expecting misunderstandings. Look into c# generic type variance, there must be a gazillion questions on SO on this subject so you’ll find it rather easy to read up on the subject. To make a long story short, `Bowl<Animal>` and `Bowl<Turtle>` are two distinct types and only under very specific circumstances can one be used in place of the other.

Comment: @InBetween thanks again for another non-answer comment.

Comment: @hvd SpadesName, BlackColor, and AceRank are derivations of Name, Color, and Rank respectively. I believe this is a language limitation and may be addressed by variance in the generic type parameter... that's the kind of answer I seek.

Comment: You're interested enough in learning that you're willing to take a difficult approach. That's good. But you'll benefit more from learning how to do this in a simpler way. You shouldn't need `MakeGenericType` or `CreateInstance` to do any of this. If you learn how to solve the same problem without doing any of that then you'll have really learned something. (And one day this more complicated stuff may be useful too.)

Comment: @ScottHannen that day has arrived.. I already have a much more complicated system; this example is a highly simplified extract of the issue.. the solution was posted below and fits my needs exactly.. I'm moving code from c++ to c# and these types of c# language limitations are things I need to get around.

Comment: @ScottHannen I learn best by example, point me to an example of the simpler way.. I'm all about doing it the right way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
using System;

public class Name { }
public class SpadesName : Name { }

public class Color { }
public class BlackColor : Color { }

public class Rank { }
public class AceRank : Rank { }

public interface IPlayingCard<out TName, out TColor, out TRank>
//where TName : Name, new()
//where TColor : Color, new()
//where TRank : Rank, new()
{ }

public class PlayingCard<TName, TColor, TRank> : IPlayingCard<Name, Color, Rank> 
    where TName : Name, new()
    where TColor : Color, new()
    where TRank : Rank, new()
{ }


public class DeckOfCards
{
    public IPlayingCard<Name, Color, Rank>[] cards;

    public DeckOfCards() { }

    public void BuildDeckOfCards()
    {
        this.cards = new IPlayingCard<Name, Color, Rank>[52];

        Type[] fpcTypeArgs = { typeof(SpadesName), typeof(BlackColor), typeof(AceRank) };
        Type fpcType = typeof(PlayingCard<,,>);
        Type constructable = fpcType.MakeGenericType(fpcTypeArgs);

        // the problem is here.. this will not cast.
        // how do I create an object using reflection and cast it to the generic base type PlayingCard<Name, Color, Rank>
        var fpc = Activator.CreateInstance(constructable);
        this.cards[0] = (IPlayingCard<Name, Color, Rank>)fpc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is pretty bad. Now One, Two, and Three are *classes.* How do you compare `IPlayingCard<SpadesName, BlackColor, OneRank>` with `IPlayingCard<SpadesName, BlackColor, TwoRank>` to determine which is greater? How do you determine whether five cards form any sort of sequence? Blackjack - I have a SevenRank and a KingRank. How do I know if I should take another card?

Comment: @ScottHannen Using full and partial specialization method overloading: the ranks have a value (depending on the game) which will allow you to create a generic comparer and sorters based on that value. The overloaded CountSuit( card) method has specializations for each suit name and will tally the hand's suit counts and look for one with 5 or more (flush). Type based Code Architecture is the way.